# SQL count occurrences of an id from another table in multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

TABLE 1 employee:

```
employee_id, first_name, last_name
     2           John    Appleseed
```

TABLE 2 performance_review:

```
employee_id, reviewer_id
     2            1
     2            3
     2            4
     1            2
     3            2
```

QUESTION: print the `first_name` and `last_name` in a single row, then how many times that id is found in the `employee_id` column, then how many times that same id is found in the `reviewer_id` column.

Example output:

```
Name               Employee_id count   Received_review count
-------------------------------------------------------------
John Appleseed              3                2
```

What I got so far (it doesn't work)

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT([employee_first_name], ' ' , [employee_last_name]) AS employee_full_name, 
    (SELECT COUNT(employee.employee_id) 
     FROM performance_review AS received_review 
     LEFT JOIN performance_review ON employee.employee_id = performance_review.employee_id) AS received_reviews
FROM 
    employee
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a clear or valid explanation of behavior. If it worked, you probably wouldn't be here looking for help. What *does* it do? What are you expecting it to do? Are there any error messages? If so what are they?

Comment: I expect the query to output the "Example output" based on the example tables. I am really blocked on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this involves separate aggregation over two different columns you need two subqueries, one for each.

Here is an example [edit] left joins should be used here because the inner joins would fail for example if the performance review table has all rows with null reviewer for a particular employee.

```
with 
  emp as (select employee_id,count(*) employee_count 
          from performance_review 
          group by employee_id),
  rev as (select reviewer_id,count(*) reviewer_count 
          from performance_review 
          group by reviewer_id) 
select 
  first_name,
  last_name,
  employee_count,
  reviewer_count
from 
 employee 
left join emp on employee.employee_id=emp.employee_id 
left join rev on employee.employee_id=rev.reviewer_id;
```

The result

| first_name | last_name | employee_count | reviewer_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Appleseed | 3 | 2 |

Comment: hope you don't mind the edit -- easier to read if it does not go off the edge of the window.

Comment: the subqueries from "with" return results, but the overall query returns no results for me. It shows no errors though

Comment: I think you need left joins here

Comment: yes that is correct. I will edit

Comment: @akulav, perhaps your are testing with different data than in the question.  It was not clear whether you wanted rows returned for example for cases where there are no non null reviewer_id. If that is the case, using left join would fix it. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Robert's answer is the clearest way  to do it but I thought I would show another way to do it with a join -- here you use a trick of doing a test and sum to count certain items.  I join both cases

```
   SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name,
          SUM(CASE WHEN e.employee_id = p.employee_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as employee_count,
          SUM(CASE WHEN e.employee_id = p.reviewer_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as reviewer_count
   FROM employee e
   LEFT JOIN performance_review p on e.employee_id = p.reviewer_id
                                  or e.employee_id = p.employee_id
   GROUP BY e.first_name, e.last_name
```

Comment: I am afraid I do not follow

Comment: @Akulav -- employee.employee does not exist in this this query.  It does not exist.  You are asking to return something here that is not there.  It does not exist.

Comment: It might seem like it exists because you have it in left join -- but that is also not right.

Comment: thx it worked as a charm. Robert's solution for some reason returns nothing, yours worked immediately, although I must admit his proposal look neater.

Comment: yeah I looked at it again... his query needed left joins not inner joins.